# Firebase Firestore: How to implement a "likes" system?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

When the currentUser taps the likeButton I run a transaction but I want to check if the user has already liked the post or not. If the user has already liked the post I want to decrease the likeCounter and change the likeButton appearance, otherwise I want to increase it.

My Firestore Database using the collection.document.collection.document.... stuff:

```
"posts":
    - "post1":
        - uid: user1
        - likeCount: 2
        - caption: "caption1"
        - "likes":
            - "user1":
                - value: true
            - "user2":
                - value: true
    - "post2":
        - uid: user1
        - likeCount: 1
        - caption: "caption2"
        - "likes":
            - "user1":
                - value: true
            - "user4":
                - value: true
    - "post3":
        - uid: user2
        - likeCount: 3
        - caption: "caption3"
        - "likes":
            - "user1":
                - value: true
            - "user3":
                - value: true
            - "user4":
                - value: true
```

This is my incrementLikes() function, which is called whenever the user taps on the likeButton

```
func incrementLikes() {
    let ref = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.document(self.post!.id!)

    Firestore.firestore().runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
        let sfDocument: DocumentSnapshot
        do {
            try sfDocument = transaction.getDocument(ref)
        } catch let fetchError as NSError {
            errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
            return nil
        }

        guard let oldLikes = sfDocument.data()?["likeCount"] as? Int else {
            let error = NSError(
                domain: "AppErrorDomain",
                code: -1,
                userInfo: [
                    NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve likes from snapshot \(sfDocument)"
                ]
            )
            errorPointer?.pointee = error
            return nil
        }
        transaction.updateData(["likeCount": oldLikes - 1], forDocument: ref)
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            ref.collection(K.likesCollection).document(currentUser.uid).delete()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.likeImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: K.heart)
            self.likeImageView.tintColor = UIColor.black
        }
        return nil
    }) { (object, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Transaction failed: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Transaction successfully committed!")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if my database is structured the correct most scalable way and also where and how should I place the observer to see if the user already liked the post or not.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If you want to check if the user has liked the post or not - that would be done by observingSingleEvent the users liked posts for that key and if it exists then decrease the likeCounter of the post. You really won't even need a query as you know the post id to see if it exists. Reading data is covered in the Getting Started Guide [Read Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once). If that's not what you're asking, can you clarify the question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Im working with Firestore not Realtime Database so the observingSingleEvent method is not available to use, is there a way I can implement it with Firestore?

Comment: Also, where inside the runTransaction method should I place the observer? thanks again

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Actually the concept of getting data once also exists in Firestore see [Get Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) and the usage is similar. Get the document and if it exists (document.exists) then decrease the likeCounter. Also, you don't need this *DispatchQueue.main.async* inside Firebase closures as UI calls are run on the main thread and networking calls are run on a background thread automatically.

Answer (score 5):

While thinking about a way of scaling this I realized instead of loading all the user likes for each post, why not save and load all the post ids the user has liked instead. A post can have 50k, 500k or 5 million likes but a user probably has maybe 1-5k max post likes. You can create a 'liked-posts' collection under the user and you can probably fetch all the posts a user has liked in one read and this will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

When I made a social media platform using Firebase, it was easier to get the `likeCounter` using the number of children in the post. Then, when checking if the `likeButton` should show if it's liked, just see if their `userId` is in the children.

The reason I found this better was because:

1. The counter could easily have bugs if the Internet wasn't secure.
2. When I wanted users to see who else had liked the post, I had to create the second branch anyways. It actually saves repeating code.

This is how I had it set up:

```
"posts":
    - "post1":
        - uid: user1
        - caption: "caption1"
                 -"LikedBy": 
                     -LikedBy:"user1"
                     -LikedBy:"user3"

// we added "LikedBy": so that instead of using likeCounter, 
//you could get the count from it's children. 
//To see if it's already liked by the user,
// find the name in this branch. If user1 finds his name in the children, 
//it'll return true. That means he's liked it.


    - "post2":
        - uid: user1
        - caption: "caption2"
               -"LikedBy":
                     -LikedBy:"user1"
                     -LikedBy:"user3"
    - "post3":
        - uid: user2
        - caption: "caption3"
              -"LikedBy":
                     -LikedBy:"user1"
                     -LikedBy:"user2"
                     -LikedBy:"user3"



// as you can see this is no longer used

"likesPerUser":
        - "user1":

        - "user2":

        - "user3":
```

Comment: but if you want to see if user liked post or no, you will load all user liked post ?

Comment: Ahh yes true. I didn’t think of that because my app was very small. I guess this isn’t the best way to do it after all.